# How to hide a div and replace it with another div in reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, css, ecmascript-6, redux

There are 2 divs. div1 and div2.
Initialy, div1 is shown and div2 is hidden.
Onclick of a button, div1 has to be hidden and div2 should be displayed in the place of div1.

Comment: just conditionally render one or the other, and change the condition when clicking the button. you can store the condition in the state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a state to indicate whether `div1` is to be shown or `div2` is to be shown. Then, add a `onClick` handler function to the button. Finally, conditionally render which component is to be shown according to that state.

Code:

```
class TwoDivs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    div1Shown: true,
  }

  handleButtonClick() {
    this.setState({
      div1Shown: false,
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleButtonClick()}>Show div2</button>
        {
        this.state.div1Shown ? 
           (<div className="div1">Div1</div>) 
           : (<div className="div2">Div2</div>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by adding a new property inside component's state. Clicking the button will simply toggle that state, and the component will re-render, due to **setState** method. Please notice that this will toggle between the two divs. If you only want to show the second one, set the new state like this: `this.setState({firstDivIsActive: false}`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstDivIsActive: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    let activeDiv;

    if (this.state.firstDivIsActive) {
      activeDiv = <div>I am one</div>;
    } else {
      activeDiv = <div>I am two</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              firstDivIsActive: !this.state.firstDivIsActive
            });
          }}
        >
          Toggle Div
        </button>
        {activeDiv}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done like below in simple HTML and JQuery as below:

```
<input id="DivType" type="hidden" value="div1" class="valid" />
<div id="div1" />
<div id="div2" />


function ToggleDiv() {
    var divType = $("#DivType").val();

    if (divType === "div1") {
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
        $('#DivType input').value = "div2";
    }
    else if (divType === "div2") {
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
        $('#DivType input').value = "div1";
    }
}
```

`ToggleDiv` will be called on `OnClick` event of button.

Not sure whether there is any better way to do it in React.

Comment: @RinoTom I wanted the solution in react, not in jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

class ToggleDivs extends React.Component {

```
state = {
  showDiv1: true,
}

handleButtonClick() {
  this.setState({
    showDiv1: !this.state.showDiv1
  });
}

render() {
  const { showDiv1 } = this.state;
  const buttonTitle = showDiv1 ? 'Div2' : 'Div1';

  const div1 = (<div className="div1">Div1</div>);
  const div2 = (<div className="div2">Div2</div>);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleButtonClick()}>Show {buttonTitle}</button>
      {showDiv1 ? div1 : div2}
    </div>
  );
}
```

}